# plone theme ui zettwerk made plone not available after installation

Tags: add-on, plone-4.x

I'm just getting started on Plone. I wanted to install zettwerk.ui, so I could easily edit plone themes, but what happened was this (I tried follow every step accordingly):

Read the instructions for the plone product here:
http://plone.org/products/zettwerk.ui

Downloaded zettwerk.ui here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zettwerk.ui/1.1.1

I saved the zettwerk zip file under Plone/zeocluster/products

Stoped plonectl, edited buildout.cfg including at the eggs part 'zettwerk.ui', ran buildout again, started plonectl.

My expectation was that I could configure the product through the web, but the result: localhost:8081 was not accessible any more - but before the installation of zettwerk everything was working fine.

The buildout output is this - I don't understand what happened, but in the end it somehow installed zettwerk correctly:

```
mbehr@S400 ~/Plone/zeocluster $ ./bin/buildout 
Updating zeoserver.
Installing client1.
Getting distribution for 'zettwerk.ui'.
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build/_sources'
warning: no files found matching '*.js' under directory 'paste'
warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'paste'

Installed /tmp/easy_install-CCHHym/zettwerk.ui-1.1.1/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg
Searching for PasteDeploy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/PasteDeploy/
Best match: PasteDeploy 1.5.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PasteDeploy/PasteDeploy-1.5.0.tar.gz#md5=f1a068a0b680493b6eaff3dd7690690f
Processing PasteDeploy-1.5.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-CCHHym/zettwerk.ui-1.1.1/temp/easy_install-DtiOVo/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/setup.cfg
Running PasteDeploy-1.5.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-CCHHym/zettwerk.ui-1.1.1/temp/easy_install-DtiOVo/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/egg-dist-tmp-WOEQZF

Installed /tmp/easy_install-CCHHym/zettwerk.ui-1.1.1/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg
Searching for Paste>=1.3
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Paste/
Best match: Paste 1.7.5.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Paste/Paste-1.7.5.1.tar.gz#md5=7ea5fabed7dca48eb46dc613c4b6c4ed
Processing Paste-1.7.5.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-CCHHym/zettwerk.ui-1.1.1/temp/easy_install-I9q1tZ/Paste-1.7.5.1/setup.cfg
Running Paste-1.7.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-CCHHym/zettwerk.ui-1.1.1/temp/easy_install-I9q1tZ/Paste-1.7.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-MQ1fJ2
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build/_sources'

Installed /tmp/easy_install-CCHHym/zettwerk.ui-1.1.1/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.7.egg
warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
Got zettwerk.ui 1.1.1.
Getting distribution for 'collective.js.jqueryui==1.10.1.2'.

Installed /tmp/easy_install-uOv0zn/collective.js.jqueryui-1.10.1.2/setuptools_git-1.0-py2.7.egg
warning: no files found matching '*.pdf' under directory 'collective'
warning: no files found matching '*.po' under directory 'collective'
warning: no files found matching '*.pot' under directory 'collective'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
Got collective.js.jqueryui 1.10.1.2.
Generated script '/home/mbehr/Plone/zeocluster/bin/client1'.
Generated interpreter '/home/mbehr/Plone/zeocluster/parts/client1/bin/interpreter'.
Installing client2.
Generated script '/home/mbehr/Plone/zeocluster/bin/client2'.
Generated interpreter '/home/mbehr/Plone/zeocluster/parts/client2/bin/interpreter'.
Updating backup.
Installing zopepy.
Generated interpreter '/home/mbehr/Plone/zeocluster/bin/zopepy'.
Updating unifiedinstaller.
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]
zettwerk.ui = 1.1.1

*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
```

What am I doing wrong - any help is welcome.